# How can I determine which parent config file is locking a web.config setting?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

When I open my ASP.NET site in IIS and try to open the .NET Trust Levels, I get an error message:

---

.NET Trust Levels
There was an error while performing this operation.

Details:

Filename: \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\web.config

Line number: 445

Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

---

I've checked a few places, but I haven't found anything that seems like it would be locking that setting.  Is there a systematic way of determining where that setting is locked?

I'm using IIS 7.5 and .NET 3.5 sp1.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't figured out how to determine exactly which file is locking any given setting, but if you select the very top node in IIS (it should be your machine name) and then open up Feature Delegation, the status bar will read 'Configuration: 'localhost' root web.config' or something similar.

From here you can modify which settings are locked at the child level.

[image: Feature Delegation in IIS]

Answer (score 0):

Both IIS and ASP.NET supports locking particular configuration sections. Typical scenarios are nested config files - for example, you may have a config file at a child directory overriding some config settings (at child level) from web site level config file. So in such case, parent can decide what sections in config files are allowed to override. I believe the concept exists in ASP.NET since version 2.0 while xml configuration appeared since IIS 7 and it also supports similar cases.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178693.aspx) to understand locking config sections in ASP.NET and [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/145/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-70-configuration/) for the same in IIS. Note that configuration file hierarchy as such start from machine config and root level web config - so in unlikely case, your web config may be trying to override allowed sections from these files.